# How do you add labels to a plotly boxplot in python?

Tags: python, plotly

I have the following code;

```
y = errnums
err_box = Box(
    y=y,
    name='Error Percent',
    boxmean='sd',
    marker=Marker(color='red'),
    boxpoints='all',
    jitter=0.5,
    pointpos=-2.0
)
layout = Layout(
    title='Error BoxPlot',
    height=500,
    width=500
)
fig = Figure(data=Data([err_box]), layout=layout)
plotly.image.save_as(fig, os.path.join(output_images, 'err_box.png'))
```

Which generates the following image;
[image: img]

What I would like to do is the following two things;

1) Add % next to the y-axis numbers. (Instead of having a traditional y-axis label saying "Error (%)")

2) Label all the vital points: mean, first quartile, third quartile, and stdev. Ideally the label would be a 4 sig-fig ('.2f') number next to the line.

Also, the stdev is the dotted line, and the diamond represents 1 sigma? 2 sigma?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For labels, try [annotations.](https://plot.ly/python/text-and-annotations/#Multiple-Annotations) You'll have to compute the quartiles and mean yourself to position the labels.

Simple example:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import *

data = Data([
    Box(
        y=[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21],
        boxpoints='all',
        jitter=0.3,
        pointpos=-1.8
    )
])
layout = Layout(
    annotations=Annotations([
        Annotation(
            x=0.3,
            y=8.822,
            text='3rd Quartile',
            showarrow=False,
            font=Font(
                size=16
            )
        )
    ])
)
fig = Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plot_url = py.plot(fig)
```

[Simple Python boxplot](https://plot.ly/~Python-Demo-Account/803)
[image: Simple boxplot with Plotly and Python]

I recommend adding and positioning the annotations in the Plotly workspace, and then viewing the generated code:

[image: Adding and editing annotations in the plotly workspace]

[image: Plotly boxplot with an annotation at the 3rd quartile]

[image: Python code to generate an annotation in Plotly]

The diamond shows the mean, and +- 1 standard deviation away from it.

It's not currently possible to add a % to the y-axis labels.

Comment: The program I'm writing needs to be self-contained, so I can't manually set the annotations. Could I have python calculate the quartiles and mean (perhaps via `numpy`) and then use it for the y-value in the annotation? The x-value could just be some default offset.

Comment: I've figured it out via `numpy.percentile`.

Comment: What about on a 3d plot? I'm not seeing a zaxis in the `Annotations` or `Annotations` class.